# Android SDK Position is invalid in China

Tags: here-api

The Android app works well in **Canada**, but when in **China**, the position is always `invalid`, and looks like the **HereGo** has the same issue.

Is that a known issue? Or should I set anything?

Answer (score 1):

The HERE Mobile SDK does not currently support China : [Map Coverage](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-premium/topics/downloadable-map-coverage.html)

Comment: Thanks Andrew! To be specifically , the SDK does not support map of China and the location positioning in China ?

Comment: That's correct, it has very limited map data for China and does not support positioning in China.